# ¿Cómo hago para convertir un valor de una variable en una constante?

Tags: vba, variables, constantes

Estoy intentando hacer una función que tome una lista de inputs del usuario en una hoja de excel y los compare con una base de datos para que me imprima en una tabla los valores que coinciden bajo ciertas condiciones, pero cuando la ejecuto o intento depurarla me sale "Error de compilación: es necesaria una expresión de cosntante" (el error aparece en la variable lim). Mi enfoque de solución fue armar varios arrays para guardar la información necesaria (número de coincidencias, posiciones dentro del input que no estuvieran vacías, etc) y luego imprimir los valores que me piden en la otra tabla.

```
Public datos() As Variant
Sub punto1()

Hoja2.Activate
Dim rango As Range
Dim lim As Integer
Set rango = Hoja1.Range("a2").End(xlDown)
cont = 0
For i = 2 To 10
    Dim pos() As Integer
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(14, i)) Then
        pos(i - 1) = i
        cont = cont + 1
    End If
Next i
max = Cells(14, 3)
min = Cells(14, 2)
Hoja1.Activate
lim = rango.Row
lim = lim - 1
If cont >= 4 Then
    If Not IsEmpty(min) Then
        If Not IsEmpty(max) Then
            If min > max Then
                MsgBox "Error: La edad inferior no puede exceder a la superior"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Dim cont2(1 To lim) As Integer
    For i = 1 To 9
        If pos(i) = 2 Or pos(i) = 3 Then
            ReDim datos(2 To lim, 2 To 2)
            For Each valor In datos
                If IsEmpty(min) And Not IsEmpty(max) Then
                    If valor <= max Then
                        cont2(valor) = cont2(valor) + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf IsEmpty(max) And Not IsEmpty(min) Then
                    If valor >= min Then
                        cont2(valor) = cont2(valor) + 1
                    End If
                ElseIf Not IsEmpty(max, min) Then
                    If valor >= min And valor <= max Then
                        cont2(valor) = cont2(valor) + 1
                    End If
                Else
                    cont2(valor) = 0
                End If
            Next valor
        Else
            ReDim datos(2 To lim, pos(i - 1) To pos(i - 1))
            For Each valor In datos
                If valor = Hoja2.Cells(14, i) Then
                    cont2(valor) = con2(valor) + 1
                End If
            Next valor
        End If
    Next i
End If
dif = 0
For i = 1 To lim - 1
    If cont2(i) >= 3 Then
        Hoja2.Cells(25 + i - dif, 4).Value = Cells(i, 1)
        Hoja2.Cells(25 + i - dif, 5).Value = Cells(i, 2)
    Else
        dif = dif + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: si probas inicializar la variable en lim = 150 , ademas fijate en la 4ta comparacion cont2(valor) = cont2(valor) + 1 vos pusiste cont2(valor) = *con2(valor) + 1* te estaria faltando una letra (t). Ojala te sirva, Saludos!